# Fluid simulation doesn't work while using a sealed container as an effector with the inflow inside?

Tags: fluid-simulation

Apologies if this question has been asked before, but i've searched around and couldn't find any solution, especially amidst all the confusion between versions before 2.8 and after.

Also to note : I'm relatively new to blender, only been tinkering with it for a couple of weeks now. I've checked normals, made sure all modifiers are applied before starting simulation. Though in this case, its only a subdivision modifier.

I'm trying to make fluid inflow inside a sealed cylinder, like magic. But after countless hours of fiddling around and searching up online, i've found that :

1. if i remove the top of the container, fluid particles will show completely.
2. creating a small cutout on the side of the cylinder will only generate a small section of the particles.
3. Removing the container as an effector allows full-flow of fluid particles.

[image: flat cylinder on top is where I want fluid to inflow while theres an outflow hidden inside the objects inside the cylinder below]

Goal : to see if i can show flow through a 'filter' medium.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after writing this, i remembered something about planar surfaces and lo and behold, everything worked like a charm! Silly me for not knowing such a simple feature existed.  [image]